# Laravel 5.4 - Method paginate does not exist. - Multiple relation filter and orderby count

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

i have this situation in my db:

> projects = id | title | slug
>
> products = id | project_id | category_id
>
> likes = id | project_id | user_id

I would like get all products with a specific "category_id", with "status" pubblished and order by project's likes (paginate for 21 products).

```
$products = Product::where('category_id', $category->id)->where('status','published')->with('project')->get()->sortBy(function($product)
        {
            return $product->project->like->count();
        })->paginate(21);
```

Without "->paginate(21)" work well, so i get this error:

> BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 74: Method paginate does
>   not exist.

Answer (score 1):

remove `get()` from this and try

```
$products = Product::where('category_id', $category->id)->where('status','published')->with('project')->sortBy(function($product)
        {
            return $product->project->like->count();
        })->paginate(21);
```

Comment: thank you for reply! but return this error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::sortBy()

Comment: please check this https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/model-sortby-relationship-count-and-paginate-results